# ÅÄÖ (swedish characters) not visible when plotting graphs in R, OSX 10.11.6

Tags: r, macos, unicode, plot, special-characters

So, I've searched forums throughout the web in search for a solution to my problem. My problem is that the Swedish characters ÅÄÖ are shown as two dots when I use these letters in plots in R-Studio. For example:

[image: Plot with title "Hjälp"]

I've experimented with various Unicode settings but with poor result. I am on a Macbook, running OSX 10.11.6. Also, my friends with older OS do not seem to have this problem.

Comment: I'm on the same OS version and it works fine for me, so it's not that. You might check your locale with `system("locale")` or `Sys.getlocale()`; any form of UTF-8 (e.g. "en_US.UTF-8") should work fine. The other thing you might try is different graphic devices; I think the Cairo ones are built to be more OS-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply alistaire,

Checking my locale results in this information, which unfortunately doesn’t say very much to me apart from that “en_SE.UTF-8” should be ok?  

> system("locale")
LANG="en_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=

I also tried the Cairo graphics device and restarted r-studio but with no luck.

Comment: `LANG` is `"en_SE.UTF-8"`, but the rest are set to the C default. I'm honestly not sure which is getting referenced here, but you may try changing them each to `"en_SE.UTF-8"` with `Sys.setlocale()` to see if it helps. When I first installed R, I recall the C defaults were causing some weird warning messages.

Comment: Did you try to use C source code i.e. \u00E4 which represents character ä? Try inserting this in plot title `Hj\u00E4lp`

Comment: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "sv_SE.UTF-8")` did the trick! Thank you very much @alistaire for your kind help. Much appreciated. Thanks for the information @Miha I'm sure that info will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","sv_SE.UTF-8")`solved my problem and ÅÄÖ is now visible when adding titles to plots. I also changed the language of my computer to Swedish as primary (English secondary), not sure if that had an effect though. One can also try with `Sys.setlocale("sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8/C/sv_SE.UTF-8/sv_SE.UTF-8")`